# Both text and border colors for ref

Tags: hyperref

My first question on this StackExchange and I hope it seems reasonable and hasn't been asked before here (I tried looking).

I'm a beginner trying to write my thesis in LaTeX. I like the idea of having bibliographic references as coloured text but would like to have borders for internal references. But when I try the following code with `hyperref`

```
\hypersetup{pdfpagemode={UseOutlines},
bookmarksopen=true,
bookmarksopenlevel=0,
hypertexnames=false,
colorlinks=true,
citecolor=blue,
linkcolor=green,
linkbordercolor={1 0 0},
urlcolor=red,
pdfstartview={FitV},
unicode,
breaklinks=true,
}
```

I believe `colorlinks=true` is blocking the border colours from coming in. Can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, `hyperref` has

- three global and exclusive types of link styles: `pdfborder` (by default), `colorlinks`, and `pdfborderstyle`, and
- six link types: cite (bibliographic references), file, link (internal references), menu, run, and url.

Here is a crude implementation that allows user to set one of the first two link styles per link type.

Update:

- Patch lower macro `\Hy@VerboseLinkStart` instead of `\hyper@link@`.

  (In places like `biblatex` and `\contentsline`, `\hyper@linkstart` and `\hyper@link` are used directly. These two macros has dependencies in `hxetex.def`, the `hyperref` driver for xetex engine, but not in `hpdftex.def` and `hluatex.def`. Therefore `\Hy@VerboseLinkStart`, the common internal of `\hyper@link[|start]` in each of drivers, is patched.)

In the following example, I use

```
\hypersetup{
  citetype=colorlinks, 
  linktype=pdfborder
}
```

to set link style `color` for all cites, and `border` for all links.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{xpatch}

\makeatletter
% change link style (color or border) per link type
\xpretocmd\Hy@VerboseLinkStart
  {\csname hyper@set@link@type@#1\endcsname}
  {}{\fail}

% set link type to color
\def\hyper@use@colorlinks{%
  \let\@pdfborder\@pdfborder@plain
  \let\Hy@colorlink\Hy@colorlink@normal
}

% set link type to border
\def\hyper@use@pdfborder{%
  \let\@pdfborder\@pdfborder@normal
  \ifHy@frenchlinks
    \let\Hy@colorlink\Hy@colorlink@french
  \else
    \let\Hy@colorlink\Hy@colorlink@plain
  \fi
}

\let\@pdfborder@normal\@pdfborder
\def\@pdfborder@plain{0 0 0}

\def\Hy@colorlink@plain#1{\begingroup}
\def\Hy@colorlink@french#1{\begingroup\fontshape{\scdefault}\selectfont}
\def\Hy@colorlink@normal#1{\begingroup\HyColor@UseColor#1}


% new \hypersetup options per link type
% usage: "citetype=[colorlinks|pdfborder]"
\def\Hy@ColorList{cite,file,link,menu,run,url}
\@for\Hy@temp:=\Hy@ColorList\do{%
  \edef\Hy@temp{%
    \noexpand\define@key{Hyp}{\Hy@temp type}{%
      \noexpand\expandafter\noexpand\let
      \noexpand\expandafter\expandafter\noexpand\csname hyper@set@link@type@\Hy@temp\endcsname
      \noexpand\csname hyper@use@##1\noexpand\endcsname%
    }%
  }%
  \Hy@temp
}
\makeatother

% user setting
\hypersetup{
  % colorlinks, % option "colorlinks" now has no effects
  citetype=colorlinks, 
  linktype=pdfborder
}

\begin{document}
Section~\ref{key}, article \cite{citekey}
\section{title}\label{key}

\begin{thebibliography}{00}
  \bibitem{citekey}
\end{thebibliography}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I tried to implement this but it seems to just remove all colours (text and border) from cites and link references. My Overleaf project can be viewed at https://www.overleaf.com/read/jwthpgnjwtbg (I put the xpatch part of your code in main.tex under "References with xpatch" and the user setting bit is in MastersDoctoralThesis.cls). The compiler also has a problem with your  ```{}{\fail}``` command? Your solution looks kind of advanced but it's definitely useful both to me and I suppose anyone else who might want to do this

Comment: @MobeusZoom In your linked overleaf project, the template loads `hyperref` package by `\AtEndPreamble`, which is very later than the patch to `\hyper@link@`, hence the patch code raises an error. You can manually load `hyperref` before patching to avoid that error. Also, to support `biblatex`, I updated answer to patch `\hyper@linkstart` instead of `\hyper@link@`.

Comment: Another change: to make the patch work for all popular engines, `\Hy@VerboseLinkStart` is patched.

Comment: Thank you! I've updated the Overleaf project accordingly. Now it compiles without error. However, while citation color is correctly controlled by ```citecolor=blue``` (see MastersDoctoralThesis.cls), my attempts to set ```linkbordercolor=red``` seem to be ignored (see Figure 1.1, Table 1.1 or Equation 1.1 in the compiled PDF)

Comment: @MobeusZoom The link borders do exists, but the pdf viewer of overleaf refuses to show them. You can download the pdf from overleaf and check those borders.